# What would We use "People stand still" or "People pause" or other terms if the time stopped completely (like in Sci-Fi movies)?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> [still](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/still) (adv): without moving : without motion
>
> Sit still. It'll just take a minute.
>
> She stood very still.

---

> [pause](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pause_1?q=pause) [intransitive]: to stop talking or doing something for a short
>   time before continuing
>
> Anita paused for a moment, then said: ‘All right’.
>
> The woman spoke almost without pausing for breath (= very quickly).
>
> I paused at the door and looked back.
>
> Pausing only to pull on a sweater, he ran out of the house.

So, **What would we use "People stand still" or "People pause" or other terms if the time stopped completely (like in Sci-Fi movies)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common verb for OP's context is metaphoric *People **froze*** (*...**were frozen in place***, etc.).

> **freeze** [(Merriam-Webster, definition 4)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freeze)
>   - *to become fixed or motionless*
>    especially, *to become **incapable of acting or speaking***

With *specific* reference to OP's *like in Sci-Fi movies*, it's also worth noting the cinematography-based term...

> **freeze-frame** [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freeze-frame)
>    *- a frame of a motion-picture film that is repeated so as to give the illusion of a static picture*

Comment: so, freeze is both transitive & intransitive?

"People froze & People were frozen"  are 2 legitimate sentences?

Comment: I don't think *transitive / intransitive* is a useful concept when considering usages like ***I'm frozen**!* or ***I'm freezing**!* They're essentially just *participles used adjectivally* - where the *past participle* usage carries no significant nuance of me having been "passively" frozen *by some unspecified agency*. The difference between *He froze* and *He was frozen* is essentially that the first refers to an ***action*** (as with *He **shivered**, He **stopped***), the second to a ***state, condition*** (as with *He was **cold**, He was **motionless***).